# UnitOfWork - Real Transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, transactions, unit-of-work

I would expose you somethings about "real transaction" and "pseudo transaction".
I think that Entity Framework implements a pseudo transaction and I'll tell you why.

```
// Partial Code

// *** Transaction scenario *** //
ObjectContext ctx = new ...
ctx.Connection.Open();
using(var t = ctx.Connection.BeginTransaction())
{
var invoice = new invoice{ price=10, Customer="myClient"};
ctx.CreateObjectSet<invoice>().AddObject(invoice);
ctx.SaveChanges();

// here I 've the ID invoice (I mean it like identity autoincrement) and I can execute some business logic basis on ID value
var client = new client { Name="Robert", Address="some address", IdInvoice=invoice.ID}
ctx.CreateObjectSet<client>().AddObject(client);
ctx.SaveChanges();

// Persistence
t.Commit(); // some error? t.Rollback
}


// *** PSEUDO Transaction scenario *** //
ObjectContext ctx = new ...

var invoice = new invoice{ price=10, Customer="myClient"};
ctx.CreateObjectSet<invoice>().AddObject(invoice);

// here I haven't invoice ID (I mean it like identity autoincrement) and I CANNOT EXECUTE ANY business logic basis on ID value
var client = new client { Name="Robert", Address="some address", IdInvoice=invoice.ID} // BAD: its value is zero
ctx.CreateObjectSet<client>().AddObject(client);

// Persistence
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Note that EF will update ID value only after SaveChanges being called and only if exist a relation between invoice and client object, otherwise nothing will works correctly.

So, my question is: is it good practice using "real transaction" on unitOwWork pattern? 
Why EF let us possibility to stumble upon bad issue like that one I've shown you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SaveChanges` can send multiple commands to the database, in your case it will send two `INSERT` statements - unbatched and one after each other. `SaveChanges` wraps the statements into a transcation that is managed by Entity Framework and you cannot control its lifetime. It starts at the beginning of `SaveChanges` and gets committed or rolled back when all statements have been sent and right before `SaveChanges` returns. This transaction is "real". Either both `INSERT`s will succeed or none.

In many scenarios this is sufficient and convenient that you don't have to care about transaction management.

In your special scenario it is not sufficient and creating and managing your own outer transaction is the correct solution. You wouldn't need that if `Customer` had a navigation property to `Invoice`. But you don't, so you need this separate transaction to get the database generated key value and still perform the whole operation in a transaction.